# Linking an off-page div section with added padding

Tags: html, css

So I apologize in advance if this question has been answered before- I tried searching but couldn't find much on it.

A designer and I are working to create this website- www.zeinal-jundi.com

This is predominantly a one-page layout using a scroll effect to navigate to different sections, although the site's Discography section does link to a separate page for each album. We also have a fixed header that allows the navigation to be visible the whole time. Originally, I had added a margin to each section of the page to accommodate the height of the fixed header. This however made the space between each section far too large, so my designer requested I find a way around this. I was able to fix it by instead adding a value to the scroll animation script that brings the section around 250px from the top, rather than to the overall top of the page (where it would then be covered by the fixed header)

So now, I've of course encountered the issue of linking to these sections from off another page- using code like the following:

```
<a href="http://zeinal-jundi.com/#bio">Biography</a>
```

This of course links back to the front page, but brings the section up to the very top, where it is hidden by our header. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way I can link to this section from another page but add an action similar to the one I have on the scrolling function that will bring it up to 250px down from the top of the page rather than the very top *without* me having to add margins to each div.

Another option of course it to just make that pesky fixed header a lot shorter, or possibly hide the site title after the page scrolls to a certain point, but our client seems pretty adamant about having the entire header visible throughout, so I of course am trying to find a work around so we won't have to rethink the entire element (if such a solution even exists).

I hope I explained this well enough! Let me know if you need to see any additional code- would love to hear your thoughts on how to achieve such a thing! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're placing the block through CSS, you can use the CSS3 [`:target` pseudo selector](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/) to position whatever section the link pointed to, e.g.:

```
:target {
    /* ... example:
     top: 250px;
     */
}
```